# Editar Informacion en componente VUE

Tags: mysql, vue.js, express

estoy intentando hacer un web con vue y express pero no tengo practicamente experiencia en esto, mi idea es tener que tengo 10 cabañas que estoy obteniendo desde la base de datos y las renderizo con vue, muestro parte de la informacion en una card y otra la mando a un calendario que esta en otro componente y hasta ahi todo bien. El problema esta en cuando quiero editar la informacion de las card pongo un boton para redireccionar a otro componente para editar la info y en el intento de esto no se como seguir, en un momento intente enviar el objeto de la card a travez de la url pero por consola me llegaba cualquier cosa menos el objeto, si alguien me puede dar una mano con esto.
Muchas gracias

Este es el app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./db");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  db.getAllCabin((data) => {
    res.json(data);
  });
});

app.put("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const dataCabin = {
    nombre_inquilino: req.body.nombre_inquilino,
    fecha_ingreso: req.body.fecha_ingreso,
    fecha_salida: req.body.fecha_salida,
  };

  db.updateCabin(req.params.id, dataCabin, (data) => {
    res.json(data);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Este es el componente de las cabañas con las cards que trae la info de la db

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div id="left" class="container m-0 p-0">
            <div class="row w-100 mt-2 mb-2" v-for="(cabana, index) in cabañas" :key="index">
                <div class="d-flex d-inline-flex">
                    <div class="card w-100" @click="send_data(cabana)">
                        <div class="card-body me-0 mt-0 mb-0">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ cabana.cabania }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Nombre Del Inquilino: {{ cabana.nombre_inquilino }}</p>
                            <p v-if="cabana.nombre_inquilino == ``">Disponible <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    width="16" height="16" fill="#3EB236" class="bi bi-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" />
                                </svg>
                            </p>
                            <p v-else>Ocupado <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="#DF2E0F"
                                    class="bi bi-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" />
                                </svg></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary justify-content-end" @click="openWindow">Editar<svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                    class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
                                </svg></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <div class="calendar">
                <CalendarioComponent :cabana="selectedCabana" @new-event="update_events" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import CalendarioComponent from "./CalendarioItem.vue";
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es';

export default {
    name: "CabañasItem",
    components: {
        CalendarioComponent,
    },
    created() {
        this.inicio();
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            cabañas: [],
            selectedCabana: null,
            calendarOptions: {
                plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
                initialView: "dayGridMonth",
                locale: esLocale,
                slotDuration: "24:00:00",
                events: [],
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        inicio() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:3000").then((res) => (this.cabañas = res.data));
        },

        send_data(cabana) {
            cabana.selected = true
            this.selectedCabana = cabana;
            const newCabana = {
                title: cabana.cabania,
                start: cabana.fecha_ingreso,
                end: cabana.fecha_salida,
                allDay: false,
            };
            this.$emit("new-event", newCabana);
        },

        update_events(newEvent) {
            this.calendarOptions.events.push(newEvent);
        },

        openWindow(cabana) {
            this.$router.push({
                name: "edit",
                params: { id: cabana }
            })

        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Y este es el componente para editar la info

```
    <template>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center align-content-center mt-5">
        <form class="col-4 ">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nombre_inquilino" class="form-label text-light">Nombre Inquilino</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_inquilino">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nombre_inquilino" class="form-label text-light">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="nombre_inquilino">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nombre_inquilino" class="form-label text-light">Fecha de Salida</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="nombre_inquilino">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="comeBack">Volver</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'edit',

    data: function () {
        return {

        }
    },

    methods: {
        comeBack() {
            this.$router.push("/")
        }
    },
}
</script>
```